# Cypher query doesn't behave as expected with multiple match blocks?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I've got the following query:

```
MATCH (u:User) WHERE u.username = "ben"
OPTIONAL MATCH (u)-[:HAS]->(pl)

//MATCH (u)-[r1:IS_AT|PREFERS|DESIRES|VALUES]->()<-[]-(fp:FitnessProgram) WHERE NOT (fp)-[:LIMITED_BY]-(pl)
//WITH u,  pl, fp, coalesce(r1.importance, 0.5) AS importance
//WITH u,  pl, fp, collect({name: fp.name, importance: importance}) AS fpTraits
//WITH u,  pl, reduce(s = 0, t IN fpTraits | s + t.importance) AS fpScore order by fpScore

MATCH (u)-[r2:IS_AT|PREFERS|DESIRES|VALUES]->()<-[]-(ns:NutritionalSupplement) WHERE NOT (ns)-[:LIMITED_BY]-(pl)
WITH u,   ns, coalesce(r2.importance, 0.5) AS importance 
WITH u,   ns, collect({name: ns.name, importance: importance}) AS nsTraits
WITH u,   ns, reduce(s = 0, t IN nsTraits | s + t.importance) AS nsScore order by nsScore desc limit 5

return u, ns.name, nsScore
```

As it is, with the 4 lines commented out, it works correctly and gives me the top 5 nutritional supplements as expected.

If I commented out the bottom block and uncomment the top block, that one works as expected too.

If I have both uncommented like below, neither block works and I get a bunch of dupes and the scores are all crazy... seems like the two matches get combined in some way I'm not understanding yet (I'm new to Neo4j)?

```
MATCH (u:User) WHERE u.username = "ben"
OPTIONAL MATCH (u)-[:HAS]->(pl)

MATCH (u)-[r1:IS_AT|PREFERS|DESIRES|VALUES]->()<-[]-(fp:FitnessProgram) WHERE NOT (fp)-[:LIMITED_BY]-(pl)
WITH u,  pl, fp, coalesce(r1.importance, 0.5) AS importance
WITH u,  pl, fp, collect({name: fp.name, importance: importance}) AS fpTraits
WITH u,  pl, fp, reduce(s = 0, t IN fpTraits | s + t.importance) AS fpScore order by fpScore desc limit 5

MATCH (u)-[r2:IS_AT|PREFERS|DESIRES|VALUES]->()<-[]-(ns:NutritionalSupplement) WHERE NOT (ns)-[:LIMITED_BY]-(pl)
WITH u, fp, fpScore,  ns, coalesce(r2.importance, 0.5) AS importance 
WITH u, fp, fpScore,  ns, collect({name: ns.name, importance: importance}) AS nsTraits
WITH u, fp, fpScore,  ns, reduce(s = 0, t IN nsTraits | s + t.importance) AS nsScore order by nsScore desc limit 5

return u, fp.name, fpScore, ns.name, nsScore
```

Answer (score 0):

What values of `fp` do you expect to have in the last block? It's not a part of the last query, so I don't think it can be in your `WITH` statements

You do not need to keep declaring `fp` in your `WITH` statements:

```
MATCH (u)-[r2:IS_AT|PREFERS|DESIRES|VALUES]->()<-[]-(ns:NutritionalSupplement) 
WHERE NOT (ns)-[:LIMITED_BY]-(pl)
WITH u, ns, coalesce(r2.importance, 0.5) AS importance 
WITH u, ns, collect({name: ns.name, importance: importance}) AS nsTraits
WITH u  ns, reduce(s = 0, t IN nsTraits | s + t.importance) AS nsScore order by nsScore desc limit 5

return u, fp.name, fpScore, ns.name, nsScore
```